# How can I change the CSS style of the GeoServer rendered map produced when I click on "Open Layer "Tab under "Common format"?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have tried many times with left no stone unturned, but all efforts came in vain.  I might be of less knowledge in this area.  Then through surfing I found this site as a newbie. I will be very obliged if I get a solution to the below mentioned scenarios.

In GeoServer when I click on "layer preview" button then "OpenLayers" for preview, rendered map aligns to the left. I need to align center and give some CSS style and others to the rendered page as below.

1. Left side panel for navigational purpose through layers made from PostGIS data.
2. Middle side is intended map.
3. Right side is for showing some attribute table for the left panel chosen layer

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: The way the question is phrased makes it pretty off-topic. Currently, it asks how to style an HTML page which incidentally happens to have a map on it. Do you have to change the default Geoserver preview or are you actually trying to create a separate website?

Comment: Sorry for behaving as factotum if i did.Yes sir, i want to build a spatial data driven website.But how  to customize the look of the geoserver served map (e.g adding legend, setting dimension of map) You may have a look in the look at "https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1NvUoakjNxwTThJMU5ybkpiR0U/edit?pli=1" if u have time, it is my webpage design.

Answer (score 3):

The layer preview in Geoserver is meant to be just a preview, to check how your data looks. It is not meant to be used as a production website.

To design a website, with a map, you can use any of the client libraries like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org), or [leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/)

To get advanced functionality like a Table of Contents, or an attribute table, you'll have to use other libraries like [GeoExtjs](http://www.geoext.org)

Comment: Sir thank u, would tell me how to develop an application where ,say,i want to see prevalence of diarrhea or other diseases against my spatial hierarchy ranges from higher to lower,a drop-down list for both diseases and spatial hierarchy to be built, where-from a map to be displayed accordingly.with several combo-boxes, and how to connect these boxes to data bases. Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is a rather wide question that you are asking. One would need to know what kind of data you have. How is the data for prevalence of diarrhea or other diseases organised? Is it a raster, or is it in attributes of your spatial layer, or is it a non spatial table in your database?

Comment: It is  a non spatial table in my database

Comment: @msi_g You'll need a WebService which can be used to query this non-spatial table. Based on this information, you can render your polygons.

Comment: @ It is a rather wide question that you are asking>>>> It attribute data (numeric) e.g 1-2-3-4 etc

Comment: @ Devdatta Tengshe I have shapefile in postgis and attribute tables in mysql . shape file field is PK_FK related with mysql.    Now how can i dynamically produce map.---------Thanks